# webassets doesn't work at sbt assembled fat jar ( docker )

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt

Static file is work well in "sbt run". But it doesn't work in docker which is build by sbt assembly.

I'm using Play 2.5.12 and I need serve only one static file so I add a file to public folder and add the route on route.conf like below.

GET         /googlee.html    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="google.html")

It work very well if I bring up the appwith "sbt run".
But when I bring it up on docker, it doesn't work.

I update log level to DEBUG but it doesn't show nothing about the error.
I guess it is a issue on "sbt assembly", but I can't figure out what cause the problem.

Below is snippet about "sbt assembly" in build.sbt

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := "my-app" + "-assembly.jar",
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("newrelic-agent") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".java"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".yaml"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".yml"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "excludes"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".txt"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".properties"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".json"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".jar"   => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html"  => MergeStrategy.first
  case "application.conf"                             => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "CHANGELOG"                                    => MergeStrategy.discard
  case manifest if manifest.contains("MANIFEST.MF")   => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
},
```